# Sublime Text parse error default(windows).sublime-keymap.2:52

Tags: javascript, json, sublimetext2

Sublime Text 2 wouldn't open. I kept getting this error:

> (Error trying to parse file: Unexpected character, expected a comma or closing 
>   bracket in c:\Users\adeleon\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 2\Packages\
>   Default (Windows).sublime-keymap.2:52)

I found the file and put it into JSON Lint. I got this error.

> Expecting 'EOF', got ','

The validator says that the problem is on line 2 of the code. I do not see any missing curly brackets. Would somebody please tell me what I am overlooking?

The link to the code is below.

https://github.com/alexwebcoder/jsonFile/blob/master/ff.txt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are missing an open bracket ([) at the very beginning of the code.